# How to install language support completely using command line?

Tags: system-installation, language-support

After a fresh ubuntu/lubuntu/xubuntu install, if you go to language support, you'll get the message prompt "**language support is not installed completely**", to install the language support.

How do you trigger the installation of language support using bash command line? In a way to automate post-installation further.

note: not sure if this only happens if you have extra languages/locales in ubuntu, but since I'm not anglo, it probably has.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sudo apt install $(check-language-support)
```

That should make the Language Support prompt shut up. :) It may install both some English and non-English packages

Comment: Never used apt to install stuff before, only apt-get and dpkg, any reason why you prefer it here and in general? And the syntax? what does the $ mean?

Comment: @fullmooninu: apt is a newer simplified tool, but apt-get works fine too. the `$(command)` syntax is equivalent to \`command\`.

Comment: So that is equivalent to **sudo apt-get install check-language-support** or to **sudo apt-get install check-language-support;check-language-support** ?

Comment: @fullmooninu: No, it's equivalent to `sudo apt-get install $(check-language-support)`. `check-language-support` is not a package - it's a command which outputs a list of packages to be installed; hence the parentheses. Hey, you asked for a bash command. If you have questions about bash, then please ask a new question.

Comment: I didn't know what check-language-support  does, as you say, lists packages to be installed. Also because in this machine it is listing nothing. Hence my question about the expanding syntax. I'll test this in a VM and give you the answer.

Comment: @fullmooninu: If `check-language-support` outputs an empty list, the language support is complete, and hence you shouldn't be prompted to install anything when opening _Language Support_. In other words: The command installs additional language support if there is something left to install.

Comment: Tested. Works fine :) Can you add the man description to your answer just for completeness? "check-language-support  - returns the list of missing packages in order  to provide a complete language environment". Tyvm.

Comment: `echo $(check-language-support)` will show what actually you have to install :) Great answer, thanx!

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson  ... check-language-support prints nothing (except a newline), but I still get the "Incomplete Language Support" pop-up on every login.   Any ideas?

Comment: @jimav: Not offhand. But if it shows up at login, your issue differs from the question asked here. I would suggest that you ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

In case, this doesn't help anyone. This error show up to me in a KDE Neon recently with JP, BR and English languages available:

```
apt-get install language-selector-common
```