# Could not install the full language support

Tags: language-support

I am trying to install hangul (korean language) in Ubuntu 18.04 and it showed this error.

[image: Could not install the full language support]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install language support completely using command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824437/how-to-install-language-support-completely-using-command-line)

Comment: That was not my solution!